# Slow random memory access in OpenCL (GPU)

Tags: memory, textures, opencl, gpu

Basically, I'm writing an OpenCL kernel which accesses global memory in a random/unpredictable manner (currently-unoptimized path tracing component of a ray tracer), and this is almost completely negating the GPU's parallelized performance advantage over the CPU (for reference, I'm running on an i7-2630QM CPU, GTX 560m GPU - performance figures below). For ease of tweaking/testing, I've written a "test" kernel which simulates this memory access pattern; it essentially provides the GPU with a large array of triangle coordinates and a list of indeces to process - for each index, it will run a ray-triangle intersection on that triangle and the 63 after, mimicking iteration through objects in an octree.

I've tried a whole slew of optimizations, including: coalesced memory access, using read-only texture memory in place of "global", loop unrolling, tweaking work group sizes and thread distribution, local memory and barriers, and manually inlining functions. These all have provided, at best, incremental performance improvements. Sorting the indeces prior to running the kernel does speed it up significantly, but for octree traversal this would require an on-GPU re-sort every iteration, and combined with other factors, leaves me doubting it will be of much help there.

I'm trying to figure out if there's some major hole that can be mended - misuse of data types, unseen optimizations, drivers too old (using OpenCL 1.0, which doesn't allow 1d textures), etc - or if I'm expecting too much of a performance increase, given the hardware I'm working with (various optimizations on the ray tracing side of things remain to be done, but I'd like to get this more general issue squared away before delving into that). Greatly appreciate any insight or suggestions in advance.

Performance figures (seconds) for 409,600 blocks of 64 triangles (run as 409,600 threads):

```
CPU (Single Thread):

Unsorted:   2.21
Sorted:     1.48 

GPU:

        Sorted  Unsorted
Texture     0.07    0.15
Global      0.02    0.25
```

Code:

```
#define IMG_WIDTH_MINUS_ONE 32767
#define IMG_HEIGHT_LOG_2 15
#define SUB(dest,v1,v2) \
      dest[0]=v1[0]-v2[0]; \
      dest[1]=v1[1]-v2[1]; \
      dest[2]=v1[2]-v2[2];

#define EPSILON 0.00001

#define CROSS(dest,v1,v2) \
      dest[0]=v1[1]*v2[2]-v1[2]*v2[1]; \
      dest[1]=v1[2]*v2[0]-v1[0]*v2[2]; \
      dest[2]=v1[0]*v2[1]-v1[1]*v2[0];

#define DOT(v1,v2) (v1[0]*v2[0]+v1[1]*v2[1]+v1[2]*v2[2])

__kernel void square(
   __global int4 *inputIndeces,
   __read_only image2d_t image,
   __global float* output,
   const unsigned int count)
{

    int global_id = get_global_id(0);
    float r_orig[3];
    float r_dir[3];
    float4 trianglePoints[3];
    int cpuStartIndex = inputIndeces[global_id].x;
    int outputIndex = inputIndeces[global_id].w;
    output[outputIndex] = 0.0;
    r_orig[0] = 0.0;
    r_orig[1] = 0.0;
    r_orig[2] = 500.0;
    r_dir[0] = 0.0;
    r_dir[1] = 0.0;
    local int counter;
    counter = 0;
    r_dir[2]= -1.0;
    float tvec[3], pvec[3], qvec[3], edgeA[3], edgeB[3];
    float det, inv_det, t, u, v;
    #pragma unroll 64
    for (int ind=cpuStartIndex;ind<cpuStartIndex+64;++ind) {



        int tIndex = ind<<2;

        int2 coords[3];


        coords[0] = (int2)(tIndex & IMG_WIDTH_MINUS_ONE,tIndex >> IMG_HEIGHT_LOG_2);
        coords[1] = (int2)((tIndex + 1) & IMG_WIDTH_MINUS_ONE,(tIndex + 1) >> IMG_HEIGHT_LOG_2);
        coords[2] = (int2)((tIndex + 2) & IMG_WIDTH_MINUS_ONE,(tIndex + 2) >> IMG_HEIGHT_LOG_2);

        trianglePoints[0] = read_imagef(image, sampler, coords[0]);
        trianglePoints[1] = read_imagef(image, sampler, coords[1]);
        trianglePoints[2] = read_imagef(image, sampler, coords[2]);

        edgeA[0] = (trianglePoints[0].w - trianglePoints[0].x);
        edgeA[1] = (trianglePoints[1].x - trianglePoints[0].y);
        edgeA[2] = (trianglePoints[1].y - trianglePoints[0].z);

        edgeB[0] = (trianglePoints[1].z - trianglePoints[0].x);
        edgeB[1] = (trianglePoints[1].w - trianglePoints[0].y);
        edgeB[2] = (trianglePoints[2].x - trianglePoints[0].z);

        CROSS(pvec,r_dir,edgeB);
        det = DOT(edgeA, pvec);

        if (det > -EPSILON && det < EPSILON) {
             continue;
        }

        inv_det = 1.0 / det;

        tvec[0] = r_orig[0] - trianglePoints[0].x;
        tvec[1] = r_orig[1] - trianglePoints[0].y;
        tvec[2] = r_orig[2] - trianglePoints[0].z;

        u = DOT(tvec, pvec) * inv_det;
        if (u < 0.0 || u > 1.0) {
                continue;
            }

            CROSS(qvec,tvec,edgeA);
            v = DOT(r_dir, qvec) * inv_det;
            if (v < 0.0 || u + v > 1.0) {
                continue;
            }
            t = DOT(edgeB, qvec) * inv_det;
            if (t > 0.001) {
                ++counter;
            }
        else {
            continue;
        }

    }
    output[outputIndex] = (float)counter;
}
```

Comment: In some small benchmarks I've done, I found that a bit of loop unrolling could help quite a lot.  I think you would need to repeat the 6 lines calculating coordinates and reading from the textures two or four times before getting to the edge calculations.  Therefore, you would need multiple trianglePoints arrays or an array of arrays.

Comment: Not much luck unfortunately. I made trianglePoints a [4][3] array, unrolling the coordinate calculations and image reads so that it's only done every 4 iterations of the main loop, but it only slowed it down significantly. Very curiously, when I removed the "if (!(loopCounter&3)) {" qualifier, it returned to its original speed. Maybe manually unrolling it interfered with an internal OpenCL optimization?

Comment: I forgot to mention that you must not add any if statements.  You have to pad your inputs so that they are a multiple of the loop unrolling factor (4 in your case).  Too bad none of this helps you.  BTW your GPUs global memory bandwidth is not very high, perhaps only 2~3 times that of your CPU so your results are not all that surprising for a kernel that does three texture reads from random coordinates.

Comment: I've actually tried something like that before (granted, not using texture memory), but naturally no dice with that either.  I just find it curious (and sufficiently frustrating) that most of the traditional data optimizations have served only to degrade performance - even dividing the 64 coordinate reads by stream processor and coalescing the input data (32-float block of respective triangles' first x coordinates, then another block of the first y, etc), then using a barrier + local memory to sum the results for that block only slowed it down. Could any of this be driver or API related?

Comment: Although, after reading your comment about if statements, along with other literature I found about conditionals and their effect on GPU performance, I think that warrants further investigation on my part :).

Comment: Just checking, did you remember to find the optimal local work group sizes again after applying each optimisation so that you can maximise occupancy?

Comment: For the most part. I didn't try it with every individual optimization, but whenever I did play around with it, a work group size of 64 was unfailingly the best-performing.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your code.. Are you counting the number of triangles intersect with the ray?

Comment: Basically, yes - the point of this was to test serial coordinate reads from random memory locations (which GPUs are especially unsuited for, as the aforementioned figures show). Some of the functionality here was so that it more closely resembled the full ray tracing code. Having since tinkered around with it a bit more, though, I've found that a special type of "semi-sorting" may actually be a solution; threads still access memory in roughly sequential order, but spending only minimal time on the pre-sorting.